# mbean to read the weblogic version details

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx, mbeans

I want to know which mbean give the weblogic version information. Also with that i need to know which patch is applied recently.I could not find the mbean which weblogic version and patch details.

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic version you can get from the domainMBean which available though WLST using both online and offline commands...

```
connect('weblogic','weblogic','t3://localhost:7001')
domainConfig()
get('DomainVersion')
'10.3.6.0'
```

or

```
readDomain('C:/Oracle/wlserver_10.3/samples/domains/wl_server')
get('DomainVersion')
'10.3.6.0'
```

For patch details I'm not aware of that information being available through an mBean I'm afraid.

Comment: i want use java code to get version details using jmx mbean.

Comment: Don't have any JMX code around to test it, but according to Enterprise Manager, it's 

    com.bea:Name=soa_domain,Type=Domain

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to fetch the version and patch details

```
         String queryString = "com.bea:Name=DomainRuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.DomainRuntimeServiceMBean";
        ObjectName objectName1;
        objectName1 = new ObjectName(queryString);
        ObjectName[] serverRuntimes = (ObjectName[]) connection.getAttribute(objectName1,
            "ServerRuntimes");

        String patch= (String) connnection.getAttribute(serverRuntimes[0], "WeblogicVersion");
```

this give the following sample value "WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0.3 PSU Patch for BUG14796139 Fri Nov 23 10:16:54 IST 2013 WebLogic Server 10.3.9.0  Tue Nov 15 08:52:36 PST 2011 1841050"